# youtube-upload and google youtube api - deeper control of upload process

Tags: python, bash, file-upload, youtube, automation

I am not a `Python` programmer, or a YouTube API specialist. This is also my first StackOverflow post. I am OK with Linux, programming generally, and `bash` scripting.

I am currently testing the [`youtube-upload` program](https://github.com/tokland/youtube-upload). I have developed a `bash` script, which determines what videos are not already uploaded by comparing md5 checksums, and creates a logged `bash` script which then uploads new videos with descriptions, tags, and titles using the `youtube-upload` `Python` app. The upload process is working well.

However, the videos uploaded do not take on the default `YouTube` channel settings, including the default playlist allocation and most advanced settings (some of which are available when using a browser to upload). This means I have to browse the uploaded videos one by one to change change the playlist the video belongs to, and most settings in the "Advanced Settings" tab for the video, which is time consuming for hundreds of short videos.

I could not find any indication on Google that the V3 YouTube API exposes playlist allocation or many advanced settings.

I have the following questions:

1. Does anyone know whether playlist allocation and advanced settings are currently exposed by the YouTube API? If not, will they ever be?
2. If the API *does* expose the control, would anyone know how I can use `bash` (or `Python` - which seems relatively easy to learn) change the playlist allocation and advanced settings for uploaded videos, or new videos being uploaded by YouTube-upload?
3. If the API *does not* expose the control, is there another method I am not aware of where I can create code that controls the browser (FireFox) to change these settings for all uploaded videos?

It seems to me that if the YouTube API does not expose these settings, then no process performing YouTube uploads can be fully automated. My goal is to fully automate the entire process, including playlist and advanced settings selection.

Comment: Welcome to SO and nice first post.

Answer (score 0):

The API to link a resource to a playlist is **PlaylistItems** at https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems.

You can follow the [**list** example](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list#examples) to see/get the playlist Ids (if you forgot it...). Then use [**insert**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/insert) method to add your resource to a playlist.

Extract from [**insert**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/insert) Reference:

> **You must specify a value for these properties:**
>
> - snippet.playlistId
> - snippet.resourceId
>
> **You can set values for these properties:**
>
> - snippet.playlistId
> - snippet.position
> - snippet.resourceId
> - contentDetails.note
> - contentDetails.startAt
> - contentDetails.endAt

Answer (score 0):

you can try this. I am not a code master neither but it works
give it a shot ytb_up based selenium

https://github.com/wanghaisheng/ytb-up
features YOU MAY NEED

1. proxy support

auto detect whether need a proxy
2. cookie support

for those multiple channels under same google account
3. schedule time publish

you can explictly specify a date and time for each video or you can set publish policy and daily public count,for example,daily count is 4,you got 5 videos,then first 4 will be published 1 day after the upload date ,the other 1 will be 2 days after the upload date
4. fix google account verify

Comment: Can you please tidy up your answer with proper formatting?